# If a conflicting rel="nofollow dofollow" is parsed (in that order) which takes precedence?

Tags: seo, google, nofollow, dofollow

If a conflicting `rel="nofollow dofollow"` is parsed (in that order) which takes precedence?

The background of this question is that I am encountering a situation where interestingly I can set a `dofollow` on a link I care about but that will always end up in the `rel="nofollow dofollow"` form so I'm interested in the effect `rel="nofollow dofollow"` would have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dofollow` does not exist so I would infer that the link would be considered as `nofollow` only.